# jquery crossslide plugin to dynamically pull images

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm working with the CrossSlide plugin (http://tobia.github.com/CrossSlide/). My setup is that I actually have two of them side by side (http://aesyliften.bwagnerdev.com). I'd like to not have the same image appear next to itself. I could do this by using a function to get the next image rather than code it in.

Does anyone have a solution or a suggestion on how to use a javascript function to issue the next image in the rotation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `sleep` parameter to 6 or 7 of both cross slide scripts.

So they are synchronized.

Comment: Yes that would indeed work, but the client likes that they do not transition at the same time.

Comment: well but then sleep is the false way to do this: `To get the static cross-fade effect you must specify the sleep option, which is the time every image will take on its own`  so its the time between 2 images always   on page load start a function with a setTimeout() which starts the second cross slide after 1 second